# About JS Action

Tags: javascript

I have a question about Action Translate in the JS file.

I already added this code

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/mage',
    'mage/translate'
],
```

but about `"Go, Pending, Accepted, Rejected"` action button not Translate still

about action button code:

please help, let me know the reason, please.
thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call the translate function like below

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'mage/translate'],function($){
    $(classRefund).html($.mage.__('Pending'));
});
```

According to your script

```
    if ($.inArray(status, array) !== -1) {
            var text = $.mage.__('Go');
            $(this).find('.col.actions').append("<span class='a123'><a href='#' class='123'>"+text+"</a></span>");
        }

    var buttonPos = "tr[data-oder-id="+col1+"] td.col.actions";
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        var classRefund = buttonPos + ' ' + 'span.refund';
        if (col1 == value.increment_id && value.refund_status == 0) {
            $(classRefund).html($.mage.__('Pending'));
        }
        if (col1 == value.increment_id && value.refund_status == 1) {
            $(classRefund).html($.mage.__('Accepted'));
        }
        if (col1 == value.increment_id && value.refund_status == 2) {
            $(classRefund).html($.mage.__('Rejected'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are right, Thanks your helpful

Comment: np....accept the answer if it is correct